# Restoring data to couchbase due to fresh couchbase installation

Tags: nosql, couchbase

We have a couchbase server that somehow had a fresh installation and all our data that was there is lost. I had managed to take the backup of /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/data/ … Now when i try to copy the data back it is not showing the couchbase server.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `… it is not showing the couchbase server ...`?

Comment: We dont see the buckets that we had earlier.. the log shows during the new installation it was deleted... we have the backup of the data folder... when we copy the contents of the backedup data folder to the new installation it does not show in the buckets.. Forgive me if i am not able to convey the message as i am new to the couchbase env

Comment: Thanks. After copying files, try restarting the `couchbase` server. In the case where `CouchDB` script is added to `systemd`, `CouchDB` server can be restarted by this command: `$ sudo systemctl restart couchdb.service`. I'm not sure about how to restart `couchbase` server in your case.

Comment: We tried that we see only the default buckets. Not our other buckets

Comment: @user3405291: Got the data buckets up!.. Copied the data contents to /data directory and created buckets with the same name using the web ui and . It worked.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it :]

Comment: @Sagar make sure to create an answer to give yourself credit for solving it :)